# The length of HList type paremeter in terms of Nat

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

Suppose I have a method without params. How can I determine a length of type parameter?

```
def func[T <: HList]: Nat = {
  // some magic
}
```

Comment: Whaaaaat........? What do you mean by `"lenght" of type paramemter` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ops.hlist.Length` operation to calculate the `Nat` length of an `HList`.

Also, getting it as an opaque `Nat` is not very useful, because you lose all the type-level information about the actual number. So you have to  get the exact `Nat` type from the function:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Length

def func[T <: HList](implicit len: Length[T]): len.Out = len()
```

Usage:

```
scala> natLen[Int :: String :: HNil]
res1: shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]] = Succ()
```

---

Getting the length as an `Int` seems more tricky. It seems you can't use `ops.nat.ToInt`, because it would require a `N <: Nat` type parameter and basically make it useless:

```
def uselessIntLen[T <: HList, N <: Nat](implicit 
  len: Length.Aux[T, N], 
  toInt: ToInt[N]
): Int = toInt()
```

I've found the following workaround using `HKernel` (of course, it's also possible to write a new typeclass `IntLength` manually). Maybe someone can help with a more direct built-in method:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.HKernelAux 

def intLen[T <: HList](implicit ker: HKernelAux[T]): Int = ker().length
```

Usage:

```
scala> intLen[Int :: String :: HNil]
res2: Int = 2
```