# Shapeless HList fill based on length of type

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, hlist

Working with `HList`s of options, I am trying to generate an `HList` with all elements equal to `None`. However, there is a problem with the implicit resolution of the `Fill` object.

The `natLength` function stems from this SO answer: [The length of HList type paremeter in terms of Nat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923040/the-length-of-hlist-type-paremeter-in-terms-of-nat).

```
type OL = Option[Double] :: Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: HNil


def emptyList[T <: HList: *->*[Option]#λ](length: Nat)(
  implicit fill: Fill.Aux[length.N, None.type, T]
): T = {
  HList.fill(length)(None)
}

def natLength[T <: HList](implicit length: Length[T]): length.Out = length()

emptyList[OL](natLength[OL])
```

The above code lets the compiler fail with this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter fill: 
shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]],None.type]{type Out = Option[Double] :: Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: shapeless.HNil}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? Generating an `HList` only based on its type's length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard way to debug implicits is to try to resolve them manually (explicitly) and look at compile errors.

```
emptyList[OL](natLength[OL])(
  implicitly[*->*[Option]#λ[Option[Double] :: Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: HNil]],
  implicitly[Fill.Aux[_3, None.type, None.type :: None.type :: None.type :: HNil]],
)
```

produces

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill[shapeless.nat._3,None.type]{type Out = None.type :: None.type :: None.type :: shapeless.HNil}
    (which expands to)  shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]],None.type]{type Out = None.type :: None.type :: None.type :: shapeless.HNil}
 required: shapeless.ops.hlist.Fill[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless.Succ[shapeless._0]]],None.type]{type Out = Option[Double] :: Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: shapeless.HNil}
    implicitly[Fill.Aux[_3, None.type, None.type :: None.type :: None.type :: HNil]],
```

What should be `T` in `def emptyList[T <: HList: *->*[Option]#λ]...`? Is it `Option[Double] :: Option[Int] :: Option[String] :: HNil`? Then why do you request implicit `Fill.Aux[length.N, None.type, T]` with `Out`-type being the same `T` while it should be `None.type :: None.type :: None.type :: HNil`.

Try

```
def emptyList(length: Nat)(
  implicit fill: Fill[length.N, None.type]
): fill.Out = {
  HList.fill(length)(None)
}

emptyList(natLength[OL]) //None :: None :: None :: HNil
```

`*->*[Option]#λ` can be context bound in `def natLength`.

Comment: Thank you, that nicely works if I call `emptyList` with a concrete type. However, it doesn't work when I call `emptyList[T]` from a method that itself has a type parameter `T <: HList`.

Comment: @Yann What is `emptyList[T]`? In my answer there is no `emptyList[T]`. In my answer it's `def emptyList(length: Nat)...` Write your code.